# Pandas dataframe perform calculations on duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with millions of rows of ad ids scraped from a website on consecutive days, in the format:

```
ad-id           Date scraped
SSE-AD-3469148  15-Apr
OAG-AD-12583686 15-Apr
OAG-AD-10476872 15-Apr
SSE-AD-3037758  15-Apr
OAG-AD-12583686 16-Apr
OAG-AD-10476872 16-Apr
SSE-AD-3037758  16-Apr
OAG-AD-10476872 17-Apr
SSE-AD-3037758  17-Apr
```

I want to output unique ad ids only, however I need to know the start and end scrape date for each ad id, like so:

```
ad-id           First scrape    Last Scrape
SSE-AD-3469148  15-Apr          15-Apr
OAG-AD-12583686 15-Apr          16-Apr
OAG-AD-10476872 15-Apr          17-Apr
SSE-AD-3037758  15-Apr          17-Apr
```

What is the most time efficient way of producing this using Pandas? I can only think of ways involving loops which for a few million rows will be very slow.

Comment: I think there are some `max` and `min` functionalities but it would still require parsing a few million dates into something comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only hope you have real dates as opposed to "17-Apr" as a a text value.

It would probably be most efficient to first sort by dates, then perform a `groupby` on the `ad-id` taking the first and last values.

You can slightly improve the speed by electing not to sort the groupby results, e.g. `df.groupby('ad-id', sort=False)...`

```
df.sort_values('Date scraped', inplace=True)
>>> df.groupby('ad-id')['Date scraped'].agg({'First Scrape': 'first', 'Last Scrape': 'last'})

                    Last Scrape First Scrape
ad-id                                       
    OAG-AD-10476872      17-Apr       15-Apr
    OAG-AD-12583686      16-Apr       15-Apr
    SSE-AD-3037758       17-Apr       15-Apr
    SSE-AD-3469148       15-Apr       15-Apr
```

**Timings with 1 million records**

```
np.random.seed(0)
ad_id = ['SSE-' + str(i) for i in np.random.random_integers(1, 500, 1000000)]
ts = pd.to_datetime(['{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(year, month, day) for year, month, day in zip(years, months, days)])
df = pd.DataFrame({'ad-id': ad_id, 'Date scraped': ts})

%%timeit -n 10
df.sort_values('Date scraped', inplace=True)
df.groupby('ad-id')['Date scraped'].agg({'First Scrape': 'first', 'Last Scrape': 'last'})
10 loops, best of 3: 277 ms per loop

>>> df.groupby('ad-id')['Date scraped'].agg({'First Scrape': 'first', 'Last Scrape': 'last'}).head()
        Last Scrape First Scrape
ad-id                           
SSE-1    2015-12-28   2000-01-02
SSE-10   2015-12-25   2000-01-01
SSE-100  2015-12-25   2000-01-01
SSE-101  2015-12-26   2000-01-05
SSE-102  2015-12-28   2000-01-01

# Slightly faster if you don't sort the results.
%%timeit -n 10
df.sort_values('Date scraped', inplace=True)
df.groupby('ad-id', sort=False)['Date scraped'].agg({'First Scrape': 'first', 'Last Scrape': 'last'})
10 loops, best of 3: 268 ms per loop
```

Comment: Alexander, there are actually a lot of extra columns that I didn't include in the OP.  Each of the extra columns should be unique to the ad-id, so I guess I could groupby all of the extra columns, but is there a generalised way to retain these extra columns?

Comment: `df2 = df.groupby('ad-id').first()` `df2.rename(columns={'Date scraped': 'First Scrape'})` `last_scrape = df.groupby('ad-id')['Date scraped'].agg({'Last Scrape': 'last'})` `df2 = df2.join(last_scrape)`